# Generate QStringList from a line in a txt file

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on a small side project with Pokemon types. The idea is to, from a .txt file, recover the type on the combo box and show it in the corresponding list view. [image: This is the base idea of what it will look like:]

The .txt file will be structured like this:

```
Type a
Type b, Type c, Type d
Type e, Type f

Type b
Type f, Type e
Type c, Type a

Type c
Type b
Type a

Type d

Type a
```

And so on and so forth. The first line of each group is the type selected by the user from a combo box, the second would be types that kind has advantages over and the last types that kind is weak against.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to take said an specific line from the .txt and making it into a QStringList that will be displayed on the List Views. I'm trying to avoid putting everything in code and I decided to try using .txt files for the first time.

Comment: Using a map sounds like a good idea, but I'm confused as to how to specify lines when reading the file

Comment: Look at `QSettings`. This class can read/write text files (.ini) where every value can be named. Also this class supports arrays in text files